# Stop animation after hovering parent item

Tags: jquery, animation, drop-down-menu, slidetoggle

### I am using a [responsive navigation menu](http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/Responsive-Multi-Level-Flat-Menu/81104),
which doesn’t include a drop down animation.

So I used this for the animation//

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".test").hover(function () {
    $(".sub-menu").slideToggle("slow", function () {});
    });
});
```

Now, when I hover over the parent item the menu slides open but once I try to hover over the child links the menu just closes.

I did a little research and tried adding `.stop()` after `$(".sub-menu")` but it still doesn't work.

My question is,
Why isn't the sub menu staying open after hovering when using `.stop()`?

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/72qp5/).

Comment: The easiest answer was deleted, will post here, since it's not mine `$('.test').parent().hover()...`. http://jsfiddle.net/72qp5/3/ That's all. ;)

Comment: The `stop()` btw is only for creating an experience, when hovering fast on and off the link, defines if the several "hover-overs" should be dequeued sequentially, means, you are away from the link, but it still springs up and down.

Comment: @dollarvar Thanks for the explanation. I wasn't sure what you meant so I deleted `.stop()` and tested the menu out and it just kept animating. Like if I rolled over the link 4 times it would open and close 4 times. Replacing the `.stop()` stop that. Btw, I'm not a professional, so sorry if I just repeated what you said in simpler terms..

Comment: No, you are welcome, after rereading my comment I wondered anyway. Haha

Comment: @dollarvar not sure if the comments is the right way to ask but I was wondering if you could possibly help me with another small issue regarding the menu - mobile version. When I am on my computer, resize the browser and hover over "Resources" the animation doesn't stop. Do you know how to fix this for mobile? Or should I post as a new question?

Comment: Sure, but is this replicable in jsfiddle? And what do you mean with "Animation"? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to add hover to parent `li` as hover on `a` gets released when you move onto sub nav

HTML

```
<DIV ID="NXVI">

    <nav>

        <ul class="menu">

            <li><a href="/">FRONT</a></li>

            <li><a href="/about">ABOUT</a></li>

            <li class="contains-sub-menu"><a class="test" href="#">RESOURCES</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="/overlays">Overlays</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Packs</a>
                        <ul class="subb-menu">
                            <li><a href="/overlay-packs">Overlay Packs</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/texture-packs">Texture Packs</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/pngs">Pngs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/templates">Templates</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/textures">Textures</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/wallpaper">Wallpaper</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="/credit">CREDIT</a></li>

            <li><a href="/requests">REQUESTS</a></li>

        </ul>

    </nav>

    <a id="touch-menu" class="mobile-menu" href="#">Menu</a>

</DIV>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".contains-sub-menu").hover(function () {
        $(".sub-menu").stop().slideToggle("slow", function () {});
    });
});
```

updated fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/eyN5A/1/

Comment: I was debating on which method to use: yours or jqueryrocks, then I realized your method is very similar to my animation script, so I went ahead and used your method except I just switched the LI to have a class of "test" continued to used `$(".test")` and just added li to the beginning and it ended up working. [{FIDDLE}](http://jsfiddle.net/72qp5/4/). But then I scrolled up and read a comment that was posted by @dollarvar and decided to use the super simple `.parent()` after `$(".test")` :) So even though I used a different simpler method, I still accepted your answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, works in the fiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".test, .sub-menu").hover(function () {
        $(".sub-menu").stop().slideDown("slow");
    }, function() {
        $(".sub-menu").stop().slideUp("slow");
    });
});
```

updated fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/72qp5/2/